# Does anything else other than dronekit and dronekit stil need to be installed to run the hello.py program on the Quick Start page?

Tags: dronekit-python

I followed the instructions on this page:
http://python.dronekit.io/guide/quick_start.html

What I've Done:

```
pip install dronekit

pip install dronekit-sitl
```

Then I created a python file with this in it:

```
print ("Start simulator (SITL)")
import dronekit_sitl

sitl = dronekit_sitl.start_default()
#connection_string = sitl.connection_string()

# Import DroneKit-Python
from dronekit import connect, VehicleMode

# Connect to the Vehicle.
print("Connecting to vehicle on: %s" % ('tcp:127.0.0.1:5760',))
vehicle = connect('tcp:127.0.0.1:5760', wait_ready=True)

# Get some vehicle attributes (state)
print ("Get some vehicle attribute values:")
print (" GPS: %s" % vehicle.gps_0)
print (" Battery: %s" % vehicle.battery)
print (" Last Heartbeat: %s" % vehicle.last_heartbeat)
print (" Is Armable?: %s" % vehicle.is_armable)
print (" System status: %s" % vehicle.system_status.state)
print (" Mode: %s" % vehicle.mode.name)    # settable

# Close vehicle object before exiting script
vehicle.close()

# Shut down simulator
sitl.stop()
print("Completed")
```

Then I ran it, and this is the error I got on the terminal:

```
olin30259168:Desktop physics$ python hello.py
Start simulator (SITL)
Starting copter simulator (SITL)
SITL already Downloaded and Extracted.
Ready to boot.
Connecting to vehicle on: tcp:127.0.0.1:5760
>>> APM:Copter V3.3 (d6053245)
>>> Frame: QUAD
>>> Calibrating barometer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 12, in <module>
    vehicle = connect('tcp:127.0.0.1:5760', wait_ready=True)
  File "/Users/physics/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dronekit/__init__.py", line 2849, in connect
    vehicle.wait_ready(True)
  File "/Users/physics/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dronekit/__init__.py", line 2199, in wait_ready
    timeout)
dronekit.APIException: wait_ready experienced a timeout after 30 seconds.
olin30259168:Desktop physics$
```

What I should be getting is:

```
Start simulator (SITL)
Downloading SITL from http://dronekit-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/sitl/copter/sitl-win-copter-3.3.tar.gz
Extracted.
Connecting to vehicle on: 'tcp:127.0.0.1:5760'
>>> APM:Copter V3.3 (d6053245)
>>> Frame: QUAD
>>> Calibrating barometer
>>> Initialising APM...
>>> barometer calibration complete
>>> GROUND START
Get some vehicle attribute values:
 GPS: GPSInfo:fix=3,num_sat=10
 Battery: Battery:voltage=12.587,current=0.0,level=100
 Last Heartbeat: 0.713999986649
 Is Armable?: False
 System status: STANDBY
 Mode: STABILIZE
Completed
```

It seems to connect, but it times out trying to calibrate the barometer, I run into the same issue when I run the examples that I cloned from this directory:

https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

This is what I installed on windows 10, if it give the same problem just resart the computer and re-run it a maximum of 4 times and then let me know.

1)  Install Python 2.7

2)  Go to https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ 
a.  Click on  get-pip.py
b.  Save it on the desktop
c.  Once downloaded double click on it

3)  Go to Command Prompt
a.  If it says C:\Users\oscar4423>
i.  Type cd C:\Python27\Scripts
b.  Once step I is done type pip like this  C:\Python27\Scripts>pip
c.  Now type pip install requests:  C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install requests

4)  Close the command prompt

5)  Go to https://git-scm.com/downloads and then click “download for Windows”

6)  Install git
7)  Open the Command Prompt and type cd C:\Python27\Scripts

8)  Type pip install git+https://github.com/3drobotics/solo-cli
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install git+https://github.com/3drobotics/solo-cli

9)  Now Install the following pip install virtualenv
10) Type pip install dronekit on the command prompt like this:
C:\Python27\Scripts> pip install dronekit

11) Type pip install dronekit-sitl on the command prompt like this:
C:\Python27\Scripts> pip install dronekit-sitl

12) pip install numpy pyparsing

13) pip install MAVProxy